# Cocoa : Unable to select provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am developing **`MAC`** app and getting **issue with selecting provisioning profile**. (I have experience for iOS app development and this steps are same. Does cocoa app needs some other steps ?)

**Issue in Short :** Profile is `NOT` listed in `"Provisioning Profile"` list in `"Xcode"`

**My Checklist :**  (Tried to Restart Xcode and MAC also)

1) Check bundle identifier in Info.plist.

2) Verify bundle identifier with provisioning profile identifier.

3) Point 1) and 2) Both match.

4) Install valid certificate in key-chain access.

5) Make sure Provisioning profile relates to that certificate.

6) Xcode -> In "Code Signing Identity", valid certificate is set.

**7) Xcode -> In "Provisioning Profile", it is not showing my provisioning profile in list, it shows "Automatic" option as selected, no profile in listing.**

8) Verified Provisioning profile install in "System Preferences" under "Profile" section, profile is installed and status "Verified".

My System details : OS X Yosemite & Xcode 6.1

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try restarting XCode (with Cmd+Q).

Comment: @LordZsolt : Restarted Xcode & even MAC also, let me add that in my checklist

Comment: Try refreshing your provisioning profiles? `Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details`

Comment: @LordZsolt : I dont have access to this developer profile's apple account, I have installed manually by export/double clicks....